# itext 7 - canvas with customized page

Tags: itext

In iText 2 , we can use PdfContentByte to set customized page-size, however, in iText 7.1.2.

```
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));


    PdfPage page = pdf.addNewPage();
    PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 2000, 800);
    pdfCanvas.rectangle(rectangle);
    pdfCanvas.stroke();
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdf, rectangle);
    PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.TIMES_ROMAN);
    PdfFont bold = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.TIMES_BOLD);
    Text title =
        new Text("The Strange Case of Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde").setFont(bold);
    Text author = new Text("Robert Louis Stevenson").setFont(font);
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph().add(title).add(" by ").add(author);
    canvas.add(p);
    canvas.close();
    pdf.close();
```

even if we set larger width, it didn't work. still keep A4 size. How can i change the pageSize correctly ?

[image]

Comment: Can you show your itext 2 code, too? Being able to use PdfContentByte to set customized page sizes sounds like an unplanned side effect...

Comment: My fault, iText 2 uses document.setPageSize(Rectangle ..);

Answer (score 2):

You are adding a new page without specifying a page size, hence the default page size (A4) is used. Please take a look at the API docs for the `addPage()` method: [addNewPage(PageSize pageSize)](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText7/latest/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/PdfDocument.html#addNewPage-com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.PageSize-). You need to pass a `PageSize` argument if you want to get a page with another size.

There's also a [setDefaultPageSize()](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText7/latest/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/PdfDocument.html#setDefaultPageSize-com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.PageSize-) method if you want to change the default page size from A4 to something else.

The `PageSize` class extends the `Rectangle` class: http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText7/latest/com/itextpdf/kernel/geom/PageSize.html